# getting 404 when trying to serve static file in express

Tags: javascript, express

I'm trying to serve a static file  in express but it's giving me a 404 error

**folder structure :**

```
/app.js
/public
    test.html
```

this is my middlware :

```
app.use(express.static('./public'));
```

but I'm getting :

> GET http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)

Comment: What is the URL you are using? Does `http://localhost:3000/test.html` work?

Comment: But which file is he supposed to find? If you really want to access a file via the root path, then you should use "index.html"

Comment: sorry I'm just a biginner in express, so to serve a static file via the root path I should use "index.html" , i tried it and it's working . but what I have to do to keep "test.html" works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make your website accessible with the "root directory", as example `http://localhost:3000`, then you have to name the main file `index.html`.

Otherwise **Express** does not know what you want, most web servers take `index.html` & `default.html` as the default file.

As an example, the website with your code is now accessible under `http://localhost:3000/test.html` because it know the static path but has not default/index file.

Comment: thank you so much, so what to do to make a diffrent file name to work like 'test.html' in my case . should i just  access this url `http://localhost:3000/test.html` ?

Comment: So you want to access the site under `http://localhost:3000`, right? Then rename the file `test.html` to `index.html`